# Bulk Quantity Shopping Cart Price Rule

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am looking to develop a bulk quantity (10+ of any single sku) shopping cart price rule that abides by these three scenarios:

1. 10 of SKU #1, 10 of SKU #2, 10 of SKU #3.  Discount for all three SKU's.
2. 10 of SKU #1, 5 of SKU #2, 6 of SKU #3.  Discount applied to SKU #1 only.
3. 8 of SKU #1, 3 of SKU #2, 1 of SKU #3.  Discount is not applied to any SKU.

I am able to apply the discount if the number of items in the cart exceed 10 in total, but it will not ignore the price rule if any single SKU is below 10 quantity.  Can Magento 1.9 allow you to check upon quantities of individual line items and not the total order quantities?

DISCLAIMER:  The full solution is limited to over a hundred different SKU's coming from only 3 specific Vendors/Suppliers.  It's unrealistic to develop a price cart rule for each of the 100+ SKU's.  (I have worked out how to narrow the Vendor/Supplier in the rule conditions.)

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the quantity of the product by the following method:

1. Get into your Shopping Cart Price rule
2. Switch to `actions`
3. Focus on `Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)` section
4. Add a rule and choose `Condition Combination`
5. Inside `If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :`, add `SKU` under `Product Attribute` and select your designated SKUs.
6. Add one more rule and select `Quantity in cart`, and select `equals or greater than`, enter 10 after that.

After that, you'll get sth like this:
[image]

Of course, remember to save your rule.